# How are the new line stringified on the client side vs server side?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following object `{g: "a\nb"}` that I stringify using `JSON.stringify`.

On the client side `'{"g":"a\nb"}'` is returned but on the server side an escaping character is added: `'{"g":"a\\nb"}'`.

### Chrome console

> [image]
>
> Google Chrome console view

### Node console

```
> a = {g: "a\nb"}
{ g: 'a\nb' }
> JSON.stringify(a)
'{"g":"a\\nb"}'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Just tried in Node works fine for me. Have you tried actually running the file in Node, not just in REPL.

Comment: @elclanrs Yes, because I am coming from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21547751/1420197). What version of Node do  you have? `node -v` outputs `v0.10.25` for me.

Comment: Same exact version, and I get same output as in browser.

Comment: @elclanrs Can you paste your output in Node, please?

Comment: See here http://imgur.com/DXpTOy6

Comment: My guess it's just a rendering issue. There is only one backslash in either case, but the node console renders it escaped. Note the double quotes in the JSON don't need escaping - instead, the Node console uses single quotes to delimit the string.

Comment: @elclanrs I can reproduce what OP has noticed on my box. Node 0.10.25 , windows. Reproduces on latest build too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rendering issue, the results are equal. It just shows them differently in the Chrome console for clarity. It shows it in a more readable format.

The Node console doesn't do any such magic.

You can observe this in the chrome console:

```
JSON.stringify({g: "a\nb"}) === '{"g":"a\\nb"}'; // true
```

Comment: A simpler way to observe such a difference is simply typing `({g: "a\nb"})` into the Chrome console which'll return `Object {g: "a↵b"}` - quite different from Node's `{ g: 'a\nb' }`

Comment: `"\\n"` also shows as `"\n"` in Chrome when evaluating it, so yes this is correct.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy that makes sense - `"\n"` shows as a line drop (which makes sense, it's for clarity when looking at the REPL result).